# Recursive function to add noise to a polygon returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have the following functions:

```
drawPolygon(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D){
    // Define the constant variables that are used to draw the polygon.
    const min_sides: number =  5;
    const max_sides: number = 20;
    const min_size: number = 10;
    const max_size: number = 200;
    const polygon_x_center: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1900 - 25 + 1));
    const polygon_y_center: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1020 - 25 + 1));
    const r: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
    const g: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
    const b: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
    const opacity: number = Math.random() * Math.floor(1);
    const num_sides = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_sides - min_sides + 1)) + min_sides;
    const size: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_size - min_size + 1)) + min_size;
    const xCenter: number = polygon_x_center + size;
    const yCenter: number = polygon_y_center + size;

    // Here we set the fill style, the blend mode, and begin drawing the polygon based on a series of points.   
    // This code is based on this post - http://scienceprimer.com/drawing-regular-polygons-javascript-canvas
    // The only tweak I really made to this was to modify to allow for the above variables to be passed in
    // rather than using hard coded values.
    const points: number[][] = new Array();
    context.fillStyle = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${opacity})`;
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";

    for(let i = 0; i <= num_sides; i++){
        let x: number = xCenter + (size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / num_sides));
        let y: number = yCenter + (size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / num_sides));
        points.push([x, y]);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        let points_with_noise: number[][] = this.addNoiseToPolygon(points, 0);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(points_with_noise[0][0], points_with_noise[0][1]);
        points_with_noise.forEach(xy => {
            context.lineTo(xy[0], xy[1]);
        })
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }
}

addNoiseToPolygon(points: number[][], recursion_depth: number){
    const recursion_limit = 3;
    let points_with_noise: number[][] = new Array();
    if(recursion_depth < recursion_limit){
        points.forEach((xy, index) => {
            if(index + 1 < points.length){
                let midpoint_x: number = (xy[0] + points[index+1][0])/2;
                let midpoint_y: number = (xy[1] + points[index+1][1])/2;
                let x1_diff_squared = Math.pow(xy[0] - midpoint_x, 2);
                let x2_diff_squared = Math.pow(points[index + 1][0] - midpoint_x, 2);
                let y1_diff_squared = Math.pow(xy[1] - midpoint_y, 2);
                let y2_diff_squared = Math.pow(points[index + 1][1] - midpoint_y, 2);
                let x_sum_of_diffs_sqaured = x1_diff_squared + x2_diff_squared;
                let y_sum_of_diffs_squared = y1_diff_squared + y2_diff_squared;
                let x_variance = x_sum_of_diffs_sqaured/3;
                let y_variance = y_sum_of_diffs_squared/3;
                let sigma_x = Math.sqrt(x_variance);
                let sigma_y = Math.sqrt(y_variance);

                let x3: number = Math.random() * ((midpoint_x + sigma_x) - (midpoint_x - sigma_x) + 1) + (midpoint_x - sigma_x);
                let y3: number = Math.random() * ((midpoint_y + sigma_y) - (midpoint_y - sigma_y) + 1) + (midpoint_y - sigma_y);

                points_with_noise.push([xy[0], xy[1]]);
                points_with_noise.push([x3, y3]);
            }
        })
        recursion_depth++;
        this.addNoiseToPolygon(points_with_noise, recursion_depth);
    } else {
        return points_with_noise;
    }
}
```

The drawPolygon function takes a canvas element and creates the points of a polygon based on a random number of sides (between 5 and 20) at a random point on the canvas.

addNoiseToPolygon takes these points and is supposed to recursively add noise to the points of the polygon and then when the function reaches it's recursion limit, it's supposed to return the final array of points so that drawPolygon can then draw those points.

However, what happens instead is that addNoiseToPolygon returns undefined. When I stepped through the code, the debugger showed the value of points_with_noise stepping back through previous calls to the addNoiseToPolygon function similar to this:

```
points_with_noise = Array(34)
points_with_noise = Array(18)
points_with_noise = Array(10)
points_with_noise = Array(6)
```

I must be missing about how my code actually works, so would someone be able to explain to me why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: your computation in `addNoiseToPolygon` boils down to `const x3 = xy[0] + (points[index+1][0] - xy[0]) * (Math.random() * 0.8164965809277261 + 0.09175170953613693), y3 = xy[1] + (points[index+1][1] - xy[1]) * (Math.random() * 0.8164965809277261 + 0.09175170953613693);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your function to take one array of points and return a new array of (modified) points. However, when you recurse, you are ignoring the return values of our own function.

Try:

```
points_with_noise = this.addNoiseToPolygon(points_with_noise, recursion_depth);
```

Comment: so my lines `recursion_depth++;
        this.addNoiseToPolygon(points_with_noise, recursion_depth);` should really be `recursion_depth++;
        points_with_noise = this.addNoiseToPolygon(points_with_noise, recursion_depth);`

Comment: Yes, I would give that a shot.